# How to avoid AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text' in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna scrape the `title` attributes of all `a` tags in the *New Texts - Section* at this [website](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page):

**Try to do it this way**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'
r = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
List = Soup.find("div",class_="enws-mainpage-widget-content").find_all('a')
for ebook in List:
    print(List.get('title'))
```

**When I run this I get this error:**

```
File "C:\Users\Özdal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Try using `print(ebook.get('title'))` instead of what you have already used.

Comment: Does the error message help? `Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: from this website: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page
I want to get the titles of new texts can anyone help me about that?

Answer (score 0):

**What happens?**

1. In your for loop, you try to grab the `title` from the `List` object not
   from each of the `ebook`. That is why the error occurred.

   Change your printing line to `print(ebook.get('title'))` and you
   will get the results.
2. To get only the `title` from `New texts - Section` you have to be more specific otherwise you grab all `a` including author, ...

   You can fix this for example this way `.select("b > i > a")`

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'
r = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
List = Soup.find("div",{"id":"enws-mainpage-newtexts-content"}).select("b > i > a")
for ebook in List:
    print(ebook.get('title'))
```

**Output**

```
The Center of the Web
Bobby Bumps Starts a Lodge
May (Mácha)
Animal Life and the World of Nature/1903/06/Notes and Comments
The Czechoslovak Review/Volume 2/No Compromise
She's All the World to Me
Their One Love
```